# How to manipulate switch function based on how many times other function was called?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make swift perform in a way that detects how many times a function is ran, and then performs a switch statement based on that.

The ideal way to do this is for swift to loop through one element in an array each time, and then go through the next one the next time the function is called, and then the next one, but I do not think this works.

```
//the doThing() function will perform after a certain condition is met
func doThing() {
var x = 0
switch x {
case: 0
doOtherThing()
x = 1
//and then I want this function to end and wait for the condition to be met to call the doThing() function, and then run the next pieces of code and so forth
case: 1
doOtherOtherThing()
x = 2
case: 2
doOtherOtherOtherThing()
default:
doNothing()
}
```

I need help troubleshooting this code because it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to move the variable `x` outside of the function:

```
var x = 0
func doThing() {
    switch x {
        case: 0
            doOtherThing()
        case: 1
            doOtherOtherThing()
        case: 2
            doOtherOtherOtherThing()
        default:
            doNothing()
    }
    x += 1
}
```

You can also make `x` `fileprivate` (if the function is in global scope) or `private` (if the function is in a struct or class) so that other code can't change it (accidentally).

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to make the loop reset, and make x = 0 after x reaches 2?

Comment: @CaptainAwesome just set it back to 0 in case 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array. It's a more natural way

```
func doOtherThing() {}
func doSomeThing() {}
var counter = 0
func doThing() {
    let array = [doOtherThing, doSomeThing]
    guard counter < array.count else { doNothing()
        return
    }
    array[counter]()
    counter += 1
}
```